# Group homomorphisms and vector space homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a certain abelian group G and a certain finite field and I have shown that G is a vector space over this field. Now I'm asked to show that every group homomorphism is a vector space homomorphism.

A group homomorphism introduces a second group H which includes the image of G as a subset. I know that H must be abelian because group homomorphisms preserve the abelian property.

The proof is clear to me if I can show that H can be made into a vector space about some field. How could I do this?

Also I am a bit confused because if I can prove this in general, the first part of the excercise doesn't make much sense because there I had to check the vector space axioms for a specific (abelian) group and a specific field.

Comment: It doesn't generally hold. Consider a finite field $F$ with $p^2$ elements, and let $G$ be $F$, forgetting multiplication (we don't forget it for the vector space structure). Then let $K$ be the subgroup generated by $1$, so $K$ is cyclic of order $p$. Consider the canonical homomorphism $G \mapsto G/K$. $H = G/K$ is a cyclic group of order $p$, hence cannot be an $F$-vector space. There probably is the additional condition that the order of $F$ is prime.

Comment: I didn't intend to conjecture that every (abelian) group can by made a vector space over every field. My question is something like can I always find a field over which a given (abelian) group forms a vector space. If I can't, I think the question I'm being asked is not well posed.

Comment: No, not every (abelian) group can be made a vector space over some field. If the group is finite, a necessary condition is that it is (isomorphic to) a direct sum of cyclic groups of prime order, all summands having the same order. That is because a finite field has prime characteristic. Every group isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n$ however can be considered as a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p \;(\cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$, and any group homomorphism between such groups is a vector space homomorphism.

Comment: Ah, ok. We didn't cover fields in detail yet, so thanks for your explanation!